# How to create an "infinite looping" horizontal ScrollView with elements that have a dynamic width (different length strings)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I need to create a Horizontal ScrollView whose elements are varying length Strings with some padding etc. When we get to the last element I want the ScrollView to keep scrolling in that direction with the first element in the collection continuing after the last element.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyuo59840qs) which works great! But it does not work for dynamic width elements. Is this code able to be tweaked for dynamic width elements or will I need to use a completely different approach? Is this something that can be achieved with iOS 17 apis only or will UIKit need to be involved?